# MySql nested select with variables not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a nested mysql query to give me the average value from a single table column (poutput_edat) every 6 rows

```
    set @rownum := 0;
    set @sum := 0;

    SELECT the_avg FROM (   
    select poutput_edat,   @rownum := (@rownum + 1) as rownum,    
    @sum := IF(@rownum mod 6 = 1,0 + poutput_edat,@sum + poutput_edat)
    as running_sum,   IF(@rownum mod 6 = 0,@sum / 6,NULL) as the_avg   
    from raw_edat /*WHERE date_edat = CURDATE()*/ ORDER BY invTime_edat desc)
    as average
```

I having trouble using this query with php mysqli, it works perfectly querying the database directly. Is this a limitation with php mysql?

Jimmy

Comment: What error message does it return?

Comment: No Error just a null result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try declaring variables in a separate `FROM` clause, e.g.:

```
SELECT the_avg FROM (   
    select poutput_edat,   @rownum := (@rownum + 1) as rownum,    
    @sum := IF(@rownum mod 6 = 1,0 + poutput_edat,@sum + poutput_edat)
    as running_sum,   IF(@rownum mod 6 = 0,@sum / 6,NULL) as the_avg   
    FROM raw_edat /*WHERE date_edat = CURDATE()*/, (SELECT @rownum := 0, @sum := 0) a 
    ORDER BY invTime_edat desc)
    as average
```

Comment: Thank you Darshan this now runs perfectly for me. A rookie mistake on my part I guess.

Jimmy